# Removing a char from a pandas dataframe column with for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that has a country column and some of that countries has "(" in it. I tried to remove all of that "(" s with this for loop:

```
for country in df_energy['Country']:
    if ')' in df_energy['Country']:
        df_energy['Country'] = df_energy['Country'].replace({'(':'', ')':''})
```

But when I print that DF again, I see all parenthesis did not removed. I'd be happy if someone say where I made a mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the loop:

```
df_energy['Country'] = df_energy['Country'].str.replace('[()]', '')
```

If you want to only replace matching `()` then:

```
df_energy['Country'] = df_energy['Country'].str.replace('\((.*)\)', r'\1')
```

Comment: This will replace all occurrences of any of the characters in any combination or order they are found, because pandas' `.str` accessors use `regex=True` by default, e.g. `')[Aaargh('` will become`'Aaargh'`

Comment: It shouldn't remove `[` as the regex `[()]` just matches `(` or `)`. And looking at the code posted by OP, it looks like they were attempting to remove all occurrences of `(` or `)` with `''`, which is what this does.

Comment: You can also remove matching `()`, added to answer.